# delete nested array item in global state when using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use hooks to delete an item in a nested state when click on the item. What's the correct way to do it?

```
const ParentComponent = () ={
  const initialState = {
  key : 1
  color: red
  child1 :{
      child2: {
        [{id: 1
          value: 10},
         {id: 2
          value: 20},
         {id: 3
          value: 30},
        ]
     }
  }
  const {itemList, setItemList} = useState(initialState)

  const handleRemoveClick = (item) => {
     setState(prevState => {
        const setItemList = prevState.child1.child2.filter(o => o.id !== item.id);
        return { newState }
        })
}
```

Expect to have item 1 removed when click on item 1

Comment: `setState({ ...this.state, items: this.state.items.slice(1) })` ???

Comment: It looks like you want to return `newState`, not `{ newState }`

Comment: @Semi-Friends, "Due to the async nature of setState, it is not advisable to use this.state to get the previous state within setState." Instead one should use this.setState((prevState) => {return { ...prevState, items: this.state.items.slice(1) };})

Comment: Appreciated the answers! I am not using this.setState, just setState. Probably should named the state something else. @AlexBroadwin

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, it's solved with the following solution:

```
  const handleRemoveClick = (index, item) => {
      let tmpList = itemList.child1.child2;
      tmpList.splice(index-1, 1 );
      setItemList({...itemList,
              child1: {
                  ...itemList.child1,
                  child2: tmpList
                  }})
```